# How to redirect outbound connections to an different IP?

Tags: windows-7, networking, browser, proxy, redirection

I have to access some external (internet) IP Address. I know for a fact that there is an internal (LAN) IP Address for the same service. I want to use the internal address everytime a program in my computer (ie. Browsers) try to access the external one.

How to configure my Windows 7 or Browser to do that?

I tried using `route` and `etc\hosts` but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in your router if you have the option. Some routers use this for parent control where if a child goes to an undesirable website the parents forward them to (EG) Google home page.

You need to check your router to see what options you have.

I'm surprised the hosts file didn't work for you.

There are lots of plugins which help, this is one example for Firefox called [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/)

Comment: I tried https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odchblbgkkchnldldakeikkjfbkllaah?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon but I haven't figured out how to use it though

Comment: Also tried https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh but couldn't make it work